# Vaadin CSS doesn't take effect

Tags: css, vaadin

I use CSS to customize some parts of the layouts in Vaadin. It worked fine until now. I tried to apply a new rule to one of my compoenents but it simply doesn't take effect, it stays how it is. I already have a similar rule which I tried to apply and change it, but the applying itself works, but any change I make to the CSS class doesn't take effect too.

I don't know why, but it seems like that at some point the CSS changes started not to do what they should, they just don't get active. I then tried to change existing rules which work fine, but these changes just don't appear on the webiste.

Is there any known bug or am I just doing something wrong what I have been doing right all the time? I can't help myself anymore, I am stuck with this for a time now.

Here are the CSS classes, as simple as it can be I guess:

```
  .v-slot-slotenabrechnung {
    padding-bottom: 21px;
    padding-left: 21px;
  }

  .v-slot-myslot {
    padding-bottom: 21px;
    padding-left: 21px;
  }
```

myslot is used at the moment and works fine. When I change the padding to 150px for example and rebuild the application and deploy it, nothing happens. And that's why my new class isn't working either. But attaching the myslot-class to  a new component works, just not any changes to it.

I can for example change the padding to 100px and then attach it to a new component, but that's results in the 21px it had before...

Comment: Have you checked with the devtools in your browser?

Comment: Yes I did, the new changes are not there after I rebuild the application.

Comment: Please show us the code, you are using.  This all "sounds" like the theme not being compiled or a more accurate rule overriding your.  Also is this SASS?  What Vaadin version?

Comment: What code do you want me to share with you?

Comment: I mean, give us some way to reproduce it.  Show us the code for the component, how you set the styles.  Show us the fragment from your sass file etc. The question as it stands is extremly hard to answer otherwise.  If the css code is not in the downloaded css, then you have not recompiled the theme.  If its in the download but takes not effect, your style is to inaccurate and something else overrides it or there is a typo.

Comment: How are you adding your custom CSS? if you're using the @StyleSheet annotation you may be having caching problems. If you're using the Chrome browser the developer tools has an option for "Disable cache (while DevTools is open)" which I've found very useful when developing. Firefox also has a similar option in it's dev tools too.

Comment: Try Ctrl+F5 in your browser - it will clear caches. If that doesn't help try to recompile theme (maven -> plugins -> vaadin -> compile theme)

Comment: Can you verify if your build is compiling your SASS file into CSS? You can add the SassCompiler plugin to the maven pom.xml in case is not doing that.

Comment: After theme compliation Vaadin creates styles.css file which is generated from your SASS. If this file exists dynamic changes to running application doesnt work in debug mode. I usually remove that file once in a while because VAADIN doesn't override it then hot deploying is availble. If this file exists application restart doenst apply any changes also.